# SQLlite Data saving in next row for radio button and checkbox instead in rows

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I made a form to get data. Input is taken in by text, radio buttons, and checkboxes. During radio and checkbox input, the saved data is going to the next rows instead of the next column, against data saved with row 1.

```
package cc.asqlsample;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private EditText editTextName;
    private EditText editTextAdd;
    private EditText editTextmail;
    private EditText editTextMob;
    private CheckBox tc;
    private RadioButton metro;
    private RadioButton nonmetro;
    private RadioButton rural;


    private Button btnAdd;
    private Button btnView;

    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        createDatabase();

        editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        editTextAdd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAddress);
        editTextmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextMail);
        editTextMob = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextMobile);
        tc = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.tc);
        metro = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.metro);
        nonmetro = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.nonmetro);
        rural = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rural);

        btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        btnView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnView);

        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    protected void createDatabase() {
        db = openOrCreateDatabase("PersonDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS persons(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR,address VARCHAR,mobile VARCHAR, email VARCHAR,city VARCHAR,terms VARCHAR);");
    }

    protected void insertIntoDB() {
        String name = editTextName.getText().toString().toUpperCase().trim();
        String add = editTextAdd.getText().toString().trim();
        String mobile = editTextMob.getText().toString().trim();
        String email = editTextmail.getText().toString().trim();


        if (name.equals("") || add.equals("") || mobile.equals("") || email.equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please fill all fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        String query = "INSERT INTO persons (name,address,mobile,email) VALUES('" + name + "', '" + add + "','" + mobile + "','" + email + "'););";
        db.execSQL(query);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    /*@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
*/
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == btnAdd) {
            insertIntoDB();
            editTextAdd.setText("");
            editTextName.setText("");
            editTextMob.setText("");
            editTextmail.setText("");
        }
        if (v == btnView) {
            showPeoples();
        }
    }


    private void showPeoples() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ViewPeople.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    public void RadioButtonClicked(View view) {
        String citytype = "";
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.metro:
                if (checked)
                    citytype = "Metro";
                break;
            case R.id.nonmetro:
                if (checked)
                    citytype = "Non Metro";
                break;
            case R.id.rural:
                if (checked)
                    citytype = "Rural";
                break;
        }
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO persons (city) VALUES('" + citytype + "');");

    }

    public void tcChecked(View view) {
        String tcstatus = "";
        boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

        if(checked)
            tcstatus = "Terms Accepted";
        else tcstatus = "Terms Not Accepted";

        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO persons (terms) VALUES('"+tcstatus+"');");

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what your problem is.  Is it that the data saved in the database is incorrect or is it something else?  Could you give a specific example of the user input and how this is being incorrectly saved?

Comment: Julie, can you help me getting values of radio and checkbox in to insertintoDB() method so that i can insert them into table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your are first saving a **persons** record partially in the method insertIntoDB() and later you would like to update the previously saved record with the values of the *city* and the *terms* columns. Here are two options to avoid creating new records when you actually want to update an existing record:

1- Save the full record in the method insertIntoDB() by also collecting the values of the *city* and the *terms* fields (columns) assuming they are properly initialized and available by then.

2- When you save the partial record in the method insertIntoDB(), obtain the AUTOINCREMENT id value (e.g., savedId) for that record from the database. Then use a SQL UPDATE statement with a WHERE clause (predicate) of "id = savedId" in the methods RadioButtonClicked() and tcChecked() to update the *city* and the *terms* columns in the existing record.

Comment: You picked the issue correctly. This is my first SQL project. Can you explain how can I use options 1 and 2. What changes are required in the code. Actually I did not want to save partial info but i created the code based on the knowledge I have.

Comment: Well, for option 1, you may try to get all the relevant values in the method insertIntoDB() and use a fuller INSERT statement involving all the columns. For option 2, you may use the insert API https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues) to get the row id value and then use the similar update API to update the original record.

Comment: I do not know how to get values in insertintoDB(). Please guide with proper steps, it would be nice.

Comment: Here is a suggestion. Declare class private String variables citytype and tcstatus and initialize them with some default values. Don't use the INSERT statements in the methods RadioButtonClicked() and tcChecked(). Just adapt those methods to set the values associated with city and terms in the previously declared variables citytype and tcstatus. Now, in the method insertIntoDB(), use those private variable values in a fuller INSERT statement like the following: INSERT INTO persons (name,address,mobile,email,city, terms) VALUES(....).

Comment: You are welcome. You may accept the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers